# Using a date variable in VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a date variable within a macro, where I have a date as input and I want to calculate the number of the day for it. Here is a piece of code:

```
Dim ntf as Date


'#An example of ntf is "12/10/2006  15:17:09" (properly formatted as a date)   
Sheets("myshhet").Select
ntf = Cells(2, 4)
Cells(6, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(" & ntf & ")"
```

but it gives me error

> run-time error '1004'

at line in which appears the formula).

Instead, if I use:

```
Dim ntf as Long
```

it works but it gives a wrong result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error is it giving you and on which line? What is the value of ntf when you step thru it? http://www.excelfunctions.net/Weekday-Function.html

Comment: @braX I edited my question, I hope it will be clearer to undertand.

Comment: Try `ntf = Cells(2, 4).Value2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Date put the date string in quotes.

```
Dim ntf As Date


'# An example of ntf is ntf = 12/10/2006  15:17:09 (properly formatted as a date

ntf = Sheets("sheet5").Cells(2, 4).Value
Sheets("sheet5").Cells(6, 6).Formula = "=WEEKDAY(""" & ntf & """)"
```

Or with the Long you need to take the Integer part and not let vba round the number.  Date time is a decimal.  So anytime your time is greater than noon, it will round to the next day.  You need to force it not to round.

```
Dim ntf As Long


'# An example of ntf is ntf = 12/10/2006  15:17:09 (properly formatted as a date

ntf = Int(Sheets("sheet5").Cells(2, 4).Value2)
Sheets("sheet5").Cells(6, 6).Formula = "=WEEKDAY(" & ntf & ")"
```

Or avoid all that and use a double instead:

```
Dim ntf As Double


'# An example of ntf is ntf = 12/10/2006  15:17:09 (properly formatted as a date

ntf = Sheets("sheet5").Cells(2, 4).Value2
Sheets("sheet5").Cells(6, 6).Formula = "=WEEKDAY(" & ntf & ")"
```

Comment: The one thing I'm wondering here is why the OP doesn't manually type the formula into the cell, or if it's just the value they're after why not use `Sheet1.Cells(6, 6) = Weekday(INT(Sheet1.Cells(2, 4)), vbMonday)`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook my guess is this is a simplified example of what the problem was.  But you would not need the `INT` if you refered directly to the cell with `Address` in the worksheet formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Good point on simplified code.  I couldn't see any difference with the `INT` in the code in my comment if the time was before or after midday, but left it in there because..... um, don't know really.

Comment: The int is needed only if converting to long.  If the OP converted it to a double then it would not need the INT.  Going to edit my answer to add that. @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Comment: Yep, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that under "wrong result" you probably mean that it gives 1 instead of 2 or etc.

This is because by default the first day in Excel is Sunday.

If you want first day Monday, then change your formula to the following:

```
Cells(6, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKDAY(" & ntf & ",2)"
```

These are the return types:

[image]

Comment: No it returns 12/11/2006 not 12/10/2006

Comment: @ScottCraner  - `WEEKDAY()` should be returning 1 to 7, based on the weekday?

Comment: with the long it returns `39062` which when formatted to a short date returns 12/11 not 12/10. at least on my computer.

Comment: I am talking the date inside the Weekday formula.

Comment: @Vityata Thanks for your answer, but it's not this the case. As wrong result I mean that it gives me 12/11/2006 instead of 12/10/2006: this happens only sometimes, not always. My first day is Monday, btw.

Comment: @ScottCraner you perfectly explained what does it happen to me.